# How do I derive the relationship between the classic magnetic field and the electromagnetic tensor?

Tags: electromagnetism, tensor-calculus

I am trying to derive the relationship between the components of the electromagnetic field tensor and the components of the magnetic field by inverting $F_{ij} = \epsilon_{ijk}\beta_{k}$. The relationship I am trying to derive is $\beta_{i} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}F^{jk}$. I am very new to tensor calculus, but my idea so far has been to use the fact that $\beta^i = \epsilon_{ijk}\partial_jA_k$, and then use the metric tensor to raise the index so I can use the last relationship.

I have gotten this far:
$F_{ij} = \epsilon_{ijk}\beta_{k} = \epsilon_{ijk}g_{kl}\beta^{l} = \epsilon_{ijk}g_{kl}\epsilon_{lmn}\partial_mA_n$, but I do not feel like this makes any sense or brings me any closer to inverting the expression.

If I am doing any fundamental mistakes or asking the question in a stupid way please let me know, as I said I am just starting out with tensors and my understanding is very limited.

Comment: Are you aware of [how to contract the Levi-Civita symbols?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Three_dimensions_2)

Comment: Not really to be honest. I tried the following using the property that $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon^{ljk} = 2\delta_i^l$ and multiplying both sides of the equality by $\epsilon^{ljk}$ which gives $\epsilon^{ljk}F_{ij} = 2\delta_i^l\beta_k$. I proceed by raising the indices using the metric tensor (written as the Kronecker delta in Cartesian coordinates):  $\epsilon^{ljk}\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}F^{mn} = 2\delta_i^l\beta_k$. However, I run into trouble because for the deltas to take on the value 1, it follows that $ i = m = j = n = l$, but that would mean the $\epsilon^{ljk} = 0$, since $j = l$.

Comment: That's almost right. It looks like you've multiplied by $\epsilon^{ljk}$ though which isn't legal as you then have three $k$s on the RHS.